# Mapbox - combining multiple checkbox filters

Tags: mapbox, filter, mapbox-gl-js

I am creating a Mapbox map in which I want multiple checkboxes to create an 'and' filter on one layer.

Here's the checkbox parts of my code so far:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="srBox" name="srBox" value="SustainableRecreation">
<label for="srBox"> Sustainable Recreation</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="hlBox" name="hlBox" value="HealthyLandscapes">
<label for="hlBox"> Healthy Landscapes</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="ovBox" name="ovBox" value="Overnight">
<label for="ovBox"> Overnight</label><br>



var checkbox = document.getElementById('srBox');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    map.setFilter('rfovProjects', ['==', ['get', 'SR'], 'Y']);
  } else {
    map.setFilter('rfovProjects', null);
  }
});

var checkbox = document.getElementById('hlBox');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    map.setFilter('rfovProjects', ['==', ['get', 'HL'], 'Y']);
  } else {
    map.setFilter('rfovProjects', null);
  }
});

var checkbox = document.getElementById('ovBox');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    map.setFilter('rfovProjects', ['==', ['get', 'OV'], 'Y']);
  } else {
    map.setFilter('rfovProjects', null);
  }
});
```

If you look at the full map example (https://codepen.io/flyinginsect2/pen/oNoQvNQ), you'll see that if you click Healthy Landscapes and then Overnight, there are a few projects that show up. However, there are no projects that are in both of these categories.

How can I combine these filters?

I have a few more that I need to add in as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve combined effect of selected filters you have to create a combined filter each time one of the individual filters change.

One way to do this is to have some `filters` object where you set key with individual filter name to `true` or `false`, depending on it's checked state.

Then on each individual filter change you iterate over `filters` keys and create and set Mapbox map filter accordingly. Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
var filters = {};

function updateFilters() {
  var compositeFilter = ['all'];
  for (let filterValue in filters) {
    if (filters[filterValue]) {
      compositeFilter.push(['==', ['get', filterValue], 'Y']);
    }
  }
  if (compositeFilter.length > 1)
    map.setFilter('rfovProjects', compositeFilter);
  else {
    map.setFilter('rfovProjects', null);
  }
}

var checkbox = document.getElementById('srBox');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  filters['SR'] = this.checked;
  updateFilters();
});

var checkbox = document.getElementById('hlBox');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  filters['HL'] = this.checked;
  updateFilters();
});

var checkbox = document.getElementById('ovBox');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  filters['OV'] = this.checked;
  updateFilters();
});
```

If you want to have OR filter, just substitute composite filter `'all'` condition with `'any'`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you! I have a follow up question... When I move these checkboxes to a new div, they stop working (https://codepen.io/flyinginsect2/pen/QWOJqRq). Do you have any thoughts on why that might be? Thanks!

Comment: Check you browser debugger console to find out why it's not working.